# what is the name of this part of android screen?

Tags: android, android-layout

first : what is official name of the black bar at bottom of the screen ?

[image]

second :

i have two layout merged together problem is part of  my second layout will hide behind this bar there is red bar behind this but is hidden this problem is in those devices has this bar

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<include layout="@layout/content_opina" />

<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/fab"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
    android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="52dp"

    android:src="@drawable/ic_add_24dp" />
```

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingTop="5dp"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:context="opina.android.ri4n.sir.opina.Opina"
    tools:showIn="@layout/activity_opina">

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1">

            <LinearLayout
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@drawable/shadow"
                android:layout_margin="5dp">


                <LinearLayout
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:background="#ffffff"
                    android:padding="5dp">

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:orientation="horizontal"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="60dp">

                        <ImageView
                            android:layout_width="40dp"
                            android:layout_height="40dp"
                            android:id="@+id/avator"
                            android:layout_margin="10dp" />

                        <LinearLayout
                            android:orientation="vertical"
                            android:layout_width="0dp"
                            android:layout_height="match_parent"
                            android:layout_weight="0.8">

                            <LinearLayout
                                android:orientation="horizontal"
                                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                android:layout_height="20dp"
                                android:hapticFeedbackEnabled="false"
                                android:layout_marginTop="10dp">

                                <TextView
                                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                                    android:text="Username ..."
                                    android:id="@+id/username"
                                    android:textColor="#000000"
                                    android:gravity="center_vertical" />
                            </LinearLayout>

                            <LinearLayout
                                android:orientation="horizontal"
                                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                android:layout_height="15dp"
                             >

                                <TextView
                                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                                            android:text="Question ... "
                                    android:id="@+id/question"
                                    android:textColor="#757575"
                                    android:gravity="center_vertical" />
                            </LinearLayout>
                        </LinearLayout>

                        <LinearLayout
                            android:orientation="vertical"
                            android:layout_width="0dp"
                            android:layout_height="match_parent"
                            android:layout_weight="0.2">

                            <TextView
                                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                                android:text="2W"
                                android:id="@+id/textView"
                                android:gravity="center" />
                        </LinearLayout>
                    </LinearLayout>

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:orientation="horizontal"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:paddingTop="10dp"
                        android:paddingBottom="10dp"
                        android:paddingRight="5dp"
                        android:paddingLeft="5dp">

                        <TextView
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="match_parent"
                            android:textColor="#000000"
                            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                            android:text="There is no such attribute in Android, to show a shadow. But possible ways to do it ... Have a 9-patch image with a shadow and set it as the background to your"
                            android:id="@+id/textView2" />
                    </LinearLayout>

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:orientation="horizontal"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="40dp">

                        <LinearLayout
                            android:orientation="horizontal"
                            android:layout_width="70dp"
                            android:layout_height="match_parent">

                            <ImageView
                                android:layout_width="20dp"
                                android:layout_height="20dp"
                                android:id="@+id/imageView"
                                android:src="@drawable/ic_favorite_24dp"
                                android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                                android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp" />

                            <TextView
                                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                                android:text="124"
                                android:textSize="12dp"
                                android:id="@+id/textView3"
                                android:gravity="left|center_vertical" />
                        </LinearLayout>

                        <LinearLayout
                            android:orientation="horizontal"
                            android:layout_width="70dp"
                            android:layout_height="match_parent">

                            <ImageView
                                android:layout_width="20dp"
                                android:layout_height="20dp"
                                android:id="@+id/imageView2"
                                android:src="@drawable/gesture"
                                android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                                android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp" />

                            <TextView
                                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                                android:text="124"
    android:textSize="12dp"
                                android:id="@+id/textView4"
                                android:gravity="left|center_vertical" />
                        </LinearLayout>

                        <LinearLayout
                            android:orientation="horizontal"
                            android:layout_width="70dp"
                            android:layout_height="match_parent">

                            <ImageView
                                android:layout_width="20dp"
                                android:layout_height="20dp"
                                android:id="@+id/imageView3"
                                android:src="@drawable/ic_comment_24dp"
                                android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                                android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp" />

                            <TextView
                                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                                android:text="124"
                                android:textSize="12dp"
                                android:id="@+id/textView5"
                                android:gravity="left|center_vertical" />
                        </LinearLayout>

                        <LinearLayout
                            android:orientation="horizontal"
                            android:layout_width="70dp"
                            android:layout_height="match_parent">

                            <ImageView
                                android:layout_width="20dp"
                                android:layout_height="20dp"
                                android:id="@+id/imageView4"
                                android:src="@drawable/ic_visibility_24dp"
                                android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                                android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp" />

                            <TextView
                                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                                android:text="124"
                                android:textSize="12dp"
                                android:id="@+id/textView6"
                                android:gravity="left|center_vertical" />
                        </LinearLayout>
                    </LinearLayout>
                </LinearLayout>
            </LinearLayout>

        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="4dp"
            android:background="@drawable/bshadow"></LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="45dp"

            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:background="#d2d2d2">

            <LinearLayout
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="0.25"
                android:gravity="center">

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="25dp"
                    android:layout_height="25dp"
                    android:id="@+id/imageView10"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_home_24dp" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="0.25"
                android:gravity="center">

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="25dp"
                    android:layout_height="25dp"
                    android:id="@+id/imageView11"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_dns_24dp" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="0.25"
                android:gravity="center">

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="25dp"
                    android:layout_height="25dp"
                    android:id="@+id/imageView12"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_notifications_24dp" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="0.25"
                android:gravity="center">

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="25dp"
                    android:layout_height="25dp"
                    android:id="@+id/imageView13"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_people_24dp" />
            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: That's a Navigation Bar, you can manipulate it by hiding/showing it or changing i's color

Comment: It's **Navigation Bar**

Comment: that is navigation bar and top is status bar and action bar xD

Comment: Bottom NavigationBar

Answer (score 0):

Android Navigation Buttons. You can also able to change it's color or hide/show them

Answer (score 0):

The Name of this bar is "Navigation Bar"